# Primefaces 3.4: DataTable and CommandLink column with f:setPropertyActionListener throws javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, primefaces, commandlink

I have this dataTable with a list of Clients and one Edit commandLink column. I need to open a dialog to show the client's data and I'm trying to use f:setPropertyActionListener to send the Client object to the bean dialog, using the variable *cli* used for the dataTable's rows:

```
<p:dataTable id="tblClients" var="cli" value="#{clientsBean.clients}" rowKey="#{cli.id}">

   <p:column>  
      <p:commandLink id="lnkEdit" value="Edit" action="#{clientBean.start}" process="@this" update="dlgClient" oncomplete="dialogClient.show()">
         <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{clientBean.client}" value="#{cli}" />
      </p:commandLink>
   </p:column>             

   <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{cli.name}" id="name">
      #{cli.name}
   </p:column>
   ...
</p:dataTable>
```

But when I hit the Edit button, throws this error:

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert test.Client@95 of type class java.lang.String to class test.Client**

I'm sure clientBean.client is Client type and its getter and setter are correct.

Is it possible to reference the dataTable variable in any way?
Do I need to implement a converter to accomplish this task?

Any help I will appreciate,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved, you can send the *cli* variable as a parameter to *start* function:

```
<p:dataTable id="tblClients" var="cli" value="#{clientsBean.clients}" rowKey="#{cli.id}">

   <p:column>  
      <p:commandLink id="lnkEdit" value="Edit" action="#{clientBean.start(cli)}" process="@this" update="dlgClient" oncomplete="dialogClient.show()">
         <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{clientBean.destinyProperty}" value="#{clientsBean.sourceProperty}" />
      </p:commandLink>
   </p:column>             

   ...
</p:dataTable>
```

It's possible to receive this parameter in clietBean like this:

```
public void start(Client currentClient) {

    this.client = currentClient;
    ...        
}
```

This can be mixed with f:setPropertyActionListener parameters.

Thanks.